# .htaccess won't redirect without arguments

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess won't redirect a URL correctly for some strange reason, whenever I attempt direct traffic from http://example.com/b70a0 to then into http://example.com/serve/?short=b70a0 I get a 404 page as if the page was not found, when of course there was never going to be a page there in the first place, I wanted to redirect the traffic from that page.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ serve.php?short=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found promptly the answer to my issue, turns out I needed to have "AllowOverride" to be allowed inside of my actual Apache settings, as that can be found by heading into the

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

folder, the following is what I found to be useful when making this resource.

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```